# Error in code to dismiss TextBox

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, compiler-warnings

I followed a previous question here on how to dismiss the keyboard when the user presses the return key (can't seem to find exact question anymore). I've implemented the Resign First Responder code and it works just fine in the app, however in order to make it work the question said to add the following line to `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.symbolstext.delegate = self;
```

Although this works well, and keyboard does dismiss Xcode gives a warning as follows,

```
Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' from incompatible type 'MemorableSettings *const __strong'
```

Is it ok to leave it like this or how do I fix this warning.

Comment: did you add <UITextFieldDelegate> to your interface ?

Comment: Yeah. The interface on my .h looks like `@interface MemorableSettings : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`

Comment: Also cleaned project. Made Warning go away but appeared again after running app